# Build a cpp application with gradle-native cpp-application & cpp-library plugins

Tags: c++, gradle, multi-module, gradle-native

I've tried to build simple cpp project with gradle-native (cpp-application & cpp-library plugins) with success.

I would like to use gradle-native for a more complex but unfortunately I failed... Even when trying to mimic samples on gradle-native/samples !
I've spend hours on it :(

Here is what I would like to do :

```
server (cpp-application) -> depends on driver or factory
driver (cpp-library) 
  |---core (cpp-library)
  |---alsa (cpp-libary with linux operating system) -> depends on core
  |---asio (cpp-library with windows operating system) -> depends on core
  |---factory (the resulting library which should use either linux or windows library) -> depends either on alsa, either on asio according to the operating system
```

or

```
server (cpp-application) -> depends on driver
driver (cpp-library)
  |---core (cpp-library)
  |---alsa (cpp-libary with linux operating system) -> depends on core
  |---asio (cpp-library with windows operating system) -> depends on core
  |---src/ (the resulting library which should use either linux or windows          library) -> depends either on alsa, either on asio according to the operating system
```

Is there anybody with a solution please ?
Thanks !
Regards